# Why is the Conditionnel Passé "Aurait-il été contraint" used here?

Tags: conditionnel

> ***Aurait-il été contraint*** de se terrer après avoir... ?
>
> ***A-t-il été contraint*** de se terrer après avoir... ?

I’d like to know how using the Conditionnel Passé changes the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: The conditional shows a hypothesis, uncertainty, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's a very subtle difference. "Aurait-il été contraint de se terrer" indicates that the speaker is speculating that he was forced to hide, whereas "A-t-il été contraint..." is simply asking the question of whether he was forced to hide.

In English, compare "Might he have been forced to hide?" and "Was he forced to hide?"

Answer (score 1):

Question + past:

> A-t-il été contraint ... ?
>   = Has he been ... ?

Question + past + hypothesis:

> Aurait-il été contraint à faire quelque chose ?
>   = Would have he been ... ?

There is an idea of hypothesis in the 2nd sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Il faut absolument avoir **le reste du contexte** pour préciser.

Plusieurs possibilités:

- 1: hypothèse sur la situation réelle (car on ne sait pas ce qui est arrivé, et où on en est, on imagine que cela aurait pu se passer).
- 2: hypothèse (qui ne s'est pas produite) selon des conditions.

Exemple 1: *le gâteau a disparu: l'aurait-il mangé ?*

Exemple 2: *Aurait-il raté/réussi son examen, s'il avait eu les bons/mauvais professeurs ?*  On peut aussi inverser !